# view pdf within my application for windows phone 8

Tags: pdf, windows-phone-8, pdfviewer

Download pdf from webservice url and saved it local storage. Then i am n't show it within my application. I need solution to show pdf using third party tool for pdfviewer or create own pdfviewer using c# for windows phone

Answer (score 1):

You should use LaunchFileAsync to Open and read a pdf file which is saved in local storage.

```
  // Access the file.
    StorageFile pdfFile = await Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync("file.pdf");

    // Launch the pdf file.
    Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchFileAsync(pdfFile);
```

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206987%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) you can know more about LaunchFileAsync.